# Dynamic tabIndex attribute in JSX + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would I set the `tabIndex` attribute on a React component conditionally in the same way, say the `disabled` attribute is set?

I need to be able to set the value and/or remove the attribute all together.

First try was to make the entire attribute key and value a variable:

```
<div { tabIndex } ></div>
```

but the compiler complains.

Second thought was to:

```
const div;
if( condition ){
   div = <div tabIndex="1"></div>
}else{
   div = <div></div>
}
```

However, this is not desirable since my actual components have tons of attributes on them and I'd end up having large amounts of duplicate code.

My only other thought was to use a ref, then use jQuery to set the `tabindex` attributes, but I would rather not have to do it that way.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do it using the [attribute spread operator](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes):

```
let props = condition ? {tabIndex: 1} : {};
let div = <div {...props} />
```

Comment: This is great for checking checkboxes, also!

Comment: Separating attribute is better option

Answer (score 11):

I believe there is a simpler way (than Aaron's suggestion).

React removes an attribute from a JSX element if that attribute's value is null or undefined. I'd need this to be confirmed by someone who knows for sure.

Therefore you can use something like this:

```
let t1 = condition ? 1 : null;
let div = <div tabIndex={t1}>...</div>;
```

The `tabIndex` attribute will be removed if `t1` is null.

Comment: This works. Many of the HTML attributes are optional. Here's a link to the type definition: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/87735e29a558c97ef0895a173269e712a199e2b7/types/react/index.d.ts#L1658

Comment: For me, it requires `undefined` instead of null. `Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'`

Comment: I confirm that it works fine with ```null```. If ```null```, attribute won't be set on JSX element.

Answer (score 1):

For example, we have three attributes, tabIndex, class and id.

```
let tabIndex;
let id;
let className = "tab";
let props = {
    tabIndex,
    className,
    id,
}
let div = <div {...props} />
```

undefined/null value props will not add in div, so the render result is

```
<div class="tab" />
```