# Disabling tabbing for dom elements not within a modal and overlay

Tags: css, reactjs, dom

I have a modal that pops up with tab-able elements. Is there something like jQuery's `:focusable` or `pointer-events: none` that would allow me use CSS to disallow focusing on items underneath the overlay?

**edit:** The problem with a JS based approach (and selectors), is that each rerender with React, the query selector would have to be run through again. I don't have control over the component rendering this modal.

Comment: Are you looking for `tabIndex`? [Dynamic tabIndex attribute in JSX + React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36523225/5867104)

Comment: I'm looking for a way around setting that on every single tab-able element underneath the modal (which I don't necessarily have control over). @VadimAidlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something along the lines of:

```
const inputs = [...document.getElementsByTagName('input')];
inputs.forEach((input) => input.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1'));

const modalInputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.my-modal input')];
modalInputs.forEach((input, index) => input.setAttribute('tabindex', index));
```

Full Example https://codepen.io/bradevans/pen/GGYxrg

Edit: I hadn't seen the reactjs tag until OP commented... I'd utilize the Modals componentDidMount lifecycle method to change the underlying DOM inputs tab indexes and change the modals at the same time or using internal state....

You may also want to store the old tab indexes and reapply them on componentWillUnmount();

Comment: The problem with a JS based approach (and selectors), is that each rerender with react, this would have to be run through again. I don't have control over the component rendering this modal.

Comment: Oh - I hadn't even seen the reactjs tag until now... but if you have control over the modal component then just hook into its componentDidMount lifecycle method and change all the underlying tab indexes within that. Then you could utilize an internal state of the modal to set the modals tab indexes.